# Автозапуск контейнера docker на Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, docker

Осваиваю docker.
Контейнеры встают, линкуются и работают. Но вот загвоздка: контейнеры не запускаются при перезапуске сервиса **docker** (либо перезагрузке сервера).

**OS:** CentOS 7

Создание контейнера

```
docker run -d --name redmine --link postgresql:postgres -v /opt/docker/redmine/files:/usr/src/redmine/files --publish 80:3000 redmine:latest
```

Запуск и остановка руками проходит замечательно:

```
docker start redmine
```

Хотя и докер должен сам создать запускать указанные контейнеры, но я ещё создал сценарий запуска для systemd

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/redmine.service 
[Unit]
Description=redmine container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start -a redmine
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop  -t 2 redmine

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

Руками запускается, а при загрузки операционки  - нет.

```
systemctl status redmine
redmine.service - redmine container
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redmine.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Ср 2015-12-16 10:57:39 MSK; 415ms ago
  Process: 10364 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 redmine (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10386 (docker)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redmine.service
           └─10386 /usr/bin/docker start -a redmine
```

Comment: [restart policy](http://serverfault.com/a/649835/292034) пробовали устанавливать для контейнера? насколько я понимаю, `/usr/lib/systemd/system/redmine.service` в таком случае не нужен.

Comment: А supervisord не пробовали?

Comment: Оба варианта рабочие. Оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ. С supervisord можно порядок запуска оформить, на сколько я понял.

Comment: @Monoceros, напишите сами, как решили задачу. здесь это [приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Т.е. ежели у меня уже контейнер запущен то я не смогу ему добавить "--restart=always"? Только через убить + запустить новый?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не правильно прочитанная документация ввела в заблуждение. 
Чтобы контейнеры запускались вместе со стартом докера, то при запуске контейнера надо указать опцию `--restart=always` . 
Например:

```
docker run --name=redmine -d --restart=always --link=memcached:memcached  --link=postgres:postgresql   --volume=/opt/docker/redmine:/home/redmine/data   --publish 80:80 --publish 443:443 sameersbn/redmine:latest
```

В этом случае всё работает.

[supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/using_supervisord/) тоже вариант решения. Использовал для других задач.

Так же не забываем об особенностях selinux. Он не давал прилинковать волум. 
Т.к. мне не нужна параноидальная система безопасности, то я выключил selinux.